# Visual Studio Code remote containers and Go GOPATH

Tags: docker, go, visual-studio-code

I created a Go container using Visual Studio Code remote containers extensions.

The project structure is like this:

```
archy-go
├── .devcontainer
│   ├── devcontainer.json
│   └── Dockerfile
└── src
    └── git.mycompany.com
        ├── main.go
        └── mycompany
            └── archy-go
                └── cmd
                    ├── createBackend.go
                    ├── createFull.go
                    ├── create.go
                    ├── root.go
                    ├── say.go
                    └── sayhello.go
```

But when I try the command `go build` inside the `git.mycompany.com` folder I get an error like this:

```
root@b570cd82e7e5:/workspaces/archy-go/src/git.mycompany.com# go build
main.go:3:8: cannot find package "git.mycompany.com/mycompany/archy-go/cmd" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/git.mycompany.com/mycompany/archy-go/cmd (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/git.mycompany.com/mycompany/archy-go/cmd (from $GOPATH)
```

What did I do wrong? Or what is the correct way to set up GOPATH in this situation?

Comment: This really helped - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension#gopath-from-goinfergopath-setting