# How to use a private github repo with vscode golang remote containers and go mods

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How do I use a private github repo with vscode golang remote containers and go mods? I found this: [VSCode remote containers and golang GOPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649407/vscode-remote-containers-and-golang-gopath) but it doesn't seem to answer how to authenticate with the remote private repo.

Comment: Possibly the same as with github. Setup the credentials for the new remote.

Comment: Have you read https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https ?